# Need help handling incorrect parameters

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I want to know how to deal when one of my routes is given an incorrect parameter. For example, in this `update` method, what if I were to receive `text` but in reality, its a number. Should I deal with that in the model file? If so, how? I'm asking this cause I was told the following: **"The post_params should be properly validated before being used."**

[image: Feedback from update method]

```
def update
  post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
  
  if post.update!(post_params)
    post_hash = post.as_json
    post_hash.merge!(authorIds: params[:authorIds])
    render json: {post: post_hash}, status: :ok
  else
    render json: {error: post.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Post_params:

```
def post_params
  params.permit(:text, :likes, :reads, :popularity, tags: [])
end
```

Post Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  # Associations
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :users, through: :user_posts, dependent: :destroy

  # Validations
  validates :text, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
  validates :popularity, inclusion: { in: 0.0..1.0 }

  def tags
    if super
      super.split(",")
    end
  end

  def tags=(value)
    if value.kind_of? Array
      super value.join(",")
    else
      super value
    end
  end

  def self.get_posts_by_user_id(user_id)
    Post.joins(:user_posts).where(user_posts: { user_id: user_id })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that validations are a model concern. It is best practice and encurreaged to use validators in the model layer, this is what they were built for.

And IMHO setting proper `StrongParams` in the controller and using validations in the model fulfill the *"The post_params should be properly validated before being used."* requirement because if one of those checks fails then the data will not be persisted in the database.

To ensure that `text` is not considered valid if it only includes a number you can extend the `text` validation like this:

```
validates :text, format: { with: /\A[^1-9\.\s]+\z/ },
                 length: { minimum: 3 },
                 presence: true
```

The regexp will match all strings that do not only contain numbers, dots (`.`), and whitespace (like `12.5`) but will allow, for example, strings that contain word characters and numbers (like `A10`). That might be enough for your use case or you might need to fine-tune the regex depending on your needs.